# add js by #attached - hook_page_alter in theme's template.php

Tags: javascript, theming

I am trying to add js by #attached, as I understand it's better from a caching perspective then drupal_add_js(). I try to use `hook_page_alter()` in `template.php`.
I have the following code:

```
function mytheme_page_alter(&$page) {
 $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme' );

  if (!isset($page['content']['#attached']))
    {
      $page['content']['#attached'] = array
      (
        'js' => array(),
      );
    }

  $page['content']['#attached']['js'][] = array($theme_path . '/test.js');
}
```

(this is adapted from http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/including-javascript-or-css-files-every-page-load-module-drupal-7, I first tried to attach [#attached] directly to $page by means of  `$page['#attached'] = array...` , but as I faced the problem described below I tried to test some code suggested by other people).

The problem is that the elements of the js are not properly set. After the `'js' => array(),` The Aptana Debugger shows what I'd expect :

[image: first dbug shot]
After `$page['content']['#attached']['js'][] = array($theme_path . '/test.js');` , however, the array values are not set:
[image: debug 2]
Still the value of `array($theme_path . '/test.js')`is what it 'should' be:
[image]

It's as if the ascription did not go through.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have no idea what your problem is. Your question is vague, what exactly is wrong and what are you expecting? Your first screenshot shows an empty `js` array, the second one shows that it has 1 item in it which is expected after that code. No problem there, is it in your third screenshot? Can you clarify/edit your question to make it clearer where the problem lies.

Comment: @Beebee I'm sorry, maybe I did not diagnose the problem correctly. The main thing is that the script  is not included.  Now, I assumed that it is because somehow the 'js' does not contain the proper element (In the second screenshot I can't see the string in the debugger that is there in the third).

Comment: It might very well be that I misunderstand the debugger/PHP workings, and the real cause of the script not working lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you're trying to use a `hook` from a `theme` template.php? (Assuming because you have `mytheme_page_alter` as your function name for `hook_page_alter`). If you're not getting the JS included, it's specifically because you can't use hooks in template.php files. You need to create a new module.

Comment: Why does it  works then if i use 'drupal_add_js()'?. 
Apparently, the code gets executed

Comment: Calling a function vs implementing a hook is very different. Hooks are "called" from other functions, but `drupal_add_js` is just a function call which will work from anywhere.

Comment: I do not understand.  mytheme_page_alter() gets executed with proper arguments. 
Besides, the https://www.drupal.org/node/1728096 says you can "Call hook_*_alter() functions which allow you to alter various parts of Drupal's internals, including the render elements in forms." in template.php?

Comment: " you can't use hooks in template.php files." - you can use *some* hooks, so please be more specific about such things.

Comment: @Beebee @Mołot this question is very wrong-headed, I asked another one at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171918/how-to-add-javascript-with-attached-and-hook-page-alter . The problem persists when the code is in the module.    
Am I right thinking that `hook_page_alter' can be called from `template.php'?

Comment: Yep apologies, didn't know you could implement alter hooks. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @Dalmaz yes as you have shown, `hook_page_alter` CAN be *implemented* in template.php