# how to add javascript with #attached and hook_page_alter

Tags: javascript, theming

I tried to add `js` to pages by means of `#attached`, as it seems to be the recommended way. From what I understand, this involves altering a render array. `hook_page_alter` seems to me like good candidate.

As per https://www.drupal.org/node/756722 (and answers below), I came with:

```
function MODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  $my_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE' );
  $page ['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'js' => array(
    'type'=>'file',
    'data' => $my_path . '/module_test.js'),
  );
}
```

The file does not get attached, though. If I use

```
drupal_add_js($my_path . '/module_test.js');
```

it does get attached (it's not a problem of the js file, access persmissions, etc.).

What is wrong?

PS. I asked a related, but apparently wrong-headed question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171881/add-js-by-attached-hook-page-alter-in-themes-template-php)

Comment: If you copy-pasted that code, you got two `js` indexes in that array. `$page['#attached']['js']['js']`

Answer (score 3):

The code that finally got it included an important change with regard to @AyeshK 's answer. The `[attached]` is not put at the top level if `$page` , but inside `['content']` or `['header']`.

The adapted code from the **Format#1** is now:

```
function MODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  $my_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE' );
  $page ['content']['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'type'=>'file',
    'data' => $my_path . '/module_test.js'
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct. However, when you have a numeric key in `[#attached][js]`, and its value is an array, you must include the `data` key.

**Format #1**

```
function MODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  $my_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE' );
  $page ['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'type'=>'file',
    'data' => $my_path . '/module_test.js'
  );
}
```

**Format #2**

```
function MODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  $my_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE' );
  $page ['#attached']['js'] = array(
    $my_path . '/module_test.js'
  );
}
```

**Format #**

```
function MODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  $my_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE' );
  $page ['#attached']['js'] = array(
    $my_path . '/module_test.js' => array(
      'type' => 'file',
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I do not get the errors now, but the js is not loaded....

Comment: @Dalmaz hope you disabled all aggregation/caching etc? If not, did you clear your caches after making any changes? Otherwise the changes might not get pulled through properly. If using drush you can "drush vset preprocess_js 0" to turn off javascript aggregation. Or just go to Config > development > performance

Comment: @Beebee Cache was turned off, I was clearing the cache. Just to make sure, I deleted the contents of the `files/js` directory, and used the drush command you suggested. It still does not work, with `drupal_add_js()` pulling properly a sister file.

Comment: just to make sure, I used the code in another theme (bartik) - I was using an omega 4 subtheme,so Ithought maybe there's something peculiar

Comment: Got it finally. The [#attached] should be inside an element of a render array, with the left-hand side of the ascription being  `['header']['attached']['js'] []=`... Now the question is: why is it so?

Comment: @Dalmaz it has to be in a renderable element because #attached needs to be run through [`render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) to get called into [`drupal_process_attached()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_attached/7) (render -> [drupal_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) -> drupal_process_attached`)