# Why does $page['content']['#attached']['js'] works , while $page['#attached']['js'] does not?

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

Trying to attach js by means of #attached by means of hook_page_alter (see [https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171918/how-to-add-javascript-with-attached-and-hook-page-alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171918/how-to-add-javascript-with-attached-and-hook-page-alter/)), I found that the following code

```
 function MODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  $my_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE' );
  $page ['content']['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'js' => array(
    'type'=>'file',
    'data' => $my_path . '/module_test.js'),
  );
}
```

works properly - it attaches the file - while

```
function MODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  $my_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE' );
  $page ['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'js' => array(
    'type'=>'file',
    'data' => $my_path . '/module_test.js'),
  );
}
```

does not. Why is it so?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render_page/7 to see it being called. You can also use [hook_page_build()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7)

Comment: You could put some `dpm()` in `drupal_render_page()` to check if `$page['#attached']['js']` is still there after `drupal_alter('page', $page)`. And if not, you could `dpm(module_implements('page_alter'))` and find out which module implementation is removing the js.

Comment: Interesting, on some SE sites, MathJAX tries to render the stuff between the dollar signs in the title in the Hot Network Questions sidebar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `#attached` elements to be processed, the array needs to be run through [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7). That never happens for the `$page` array.

Parts of it are rendered, e.g. in [page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7):

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

But never the `$page` array itself.

Comment: Are you sure? drupal_render_page() calls drupal_render($page).

Comment: What difference does it make whether I call `$page ['content']['#attached']['js'][]`  or `$page ['header']['#attached']['js'][]`?

Comment: @donquixote hmm yeah you're right. Need to unpick that tomorrow, must sleep now. Dalmaz: it makes no appreciable difference really, assuming each is rendered it'll have the same effect

Comment: Yes, `drupal_render_page()` does go through the `#attached` js BUT it's too late that point. See `drupal_render()`. The `drupal_process_attached($elements);` call happens too late. The `html.tpl.php` is already rendered, so you can't affect the attached js/css, etc. Hat tip to my coworker.