# Invoke javascript in hook

Tags: javascript, hooks

I have create a hook to alter page funcionality. It's posible invoke javascript function in hook.
          I test this function but i had this error -->  Call to undefined function alert()

```
      function catalogo_preprocess_node(&$vars)
      {
        alert("hello");
      }
```

Comment: This is by concept a bad idea. PHP is executed on server side, JS is executed client side in the visitors browser, don't do this. Hooks are meant for server side preprocess, there is no point putting a client side JS function in a hook. Use a [Drupal behavior](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview) instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add javascript with #attached and hook\_page\_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171918/how-to-add-javascript-with-attached-and-hook-page-alter)

Comment: PHP won't know anything about Javascript functions. You should write AJAX Commands instead and think of things in those terms. But it is generally a bad idea to have Javascript functions that alter page data in the way you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

D7 you can try function [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x)

```
function hook_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'your_theme') . '/js/my_script.js');
}
```

D8 You need define one or more (asset) libraries, add a *.libraries.yml file to the root of your theme folder

```
library_name:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/my_script.js: {}
```

Attaching a library in a preprocess function

```
function hook_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] =  'your_theme/library_name';
}
```